# angular json format using $http on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an angular app using $http module.
The server response looks like "{"utilisateurAnnuaire":{"id":"6"}...}" and works.

But when i try to use my app on IE 10.0.9, the response looks like "{\"utilisateurAnnuaire\":{\"id\":\"6\"}...}" and angular fail to use JSON.parse().

I don't understand why, someone have an idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Where are you seeing the JSON formatted this way? In the browser's console window? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. Are you setting the response content type to `application/json`?
2. Are you sure IE 10 is actually escaping the string? Try this out in Chrome or Firefox. IE 10 is actually pretty close to them in terms of compliance.